# Как можно сделать фон штриховкой на CSS/HTML?

Tags: html, css, svg

Можно ли сделать такой штрих, если да, то как

[image: Штрих]

Comment: Я бы не парился и просто сделал бы background-image

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Можно, используя градиент

```css
.dash {
  height: 30px;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(-60deg, #555 0, #555 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 5px);
}
```

```html
<div class="dash"></div>
```

Comment: В моём фаерфоксе криво рисуется, толщина линий разная https://i.stack.imgur.com/dp0df.png

Comment: @andreymal, особенности отрисовки в браузере. Если поставить угол наклона 90deg - линии отрисовываются нормально. Как победить - не знаю.

Comment: Chrome 60.0.3112.113, не работает сглаживание между переходами цветов (хотя, должно ли):  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kf8kU.png

Answer (score 12):

Рисуете свою полоску в `SVG`, генерируете `data:uri`, вставляете на повторяющийся фон. Никаких артефактов, векторный фон готов:

```css
.dash {
  height: 30px;
  background-image:url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,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");
  background-repeat:repeat;
  background-position:0 0;
  background-size:4px 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dash"></div>
```

Comment: Хороший ответ (+) Давненько от Вас не было новых ответов

Comment: Super....))))))